# How can I produce a projectile diagram on an inclined plane?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am able to draw the plane, the parabola mark angles and velocity… [I am certain there is a more efficient approach] What I can't do is remove the part of the parabola that falls below the plane.  I would eventually like to be able to do this for all angles of plane as a new command macro so I could easily produce different diagrams for my students. See picture
[image: path of projectile up a plane]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[left=10mm, top=15mm, right=10mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) coordinate (O)--(13,0);
    \begin{axis}[%
    hide axis,axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,
    width=12cm,
    height=5cm,
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0:10,
    ] {-(.12*x)*(x-10)};
    \draw[-latex,] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1.5,1.8) coordinate (D) node[above]{5ms$^{-1}$} ;
    \draw (O)--(axis cs:15,0) coordinate (B);
    \draw (O) -- (axis cs:11,1.32) coordinate (C);
    \end{axis}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=4](B,O,C){$15^\circ$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=5,mark={}](B,O,C);
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](C,O,D){$35^\circ$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=1.5,mark={}](C,O,D);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quick but dirty solution: Fill (O,B,C) triangle white.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[left=10mm, top=15mm, right=10mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) coordinate (O)--(13,0);
    \begin{axis}[%
    hide axis,axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left,
    width=12cm,
    height=5cm,
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0:10,
    ] {-(.12*x)*(x-10)};
    \draw[-latex,] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1.5,1.8) coordinate (D) node[above]{5ms$^{-1}$} ;
    \draw (O)--(axis cs:15,0) coordinate (B);
    \draw (O) -- (axis cs:11,1.32) coordinate (C);
    \end{axis}
\fill [white] (O) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;    
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=4](B,O,C){$15^\circ$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=5,mark={}](B,O,C);
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](C,O,D){$35^\circ$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=1.5,mark={}](C,O,D);
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A really obvious fix now i see it. I was thinking i would need to clip the parabola or somehow calculate the second point of intersection of the parabola and the plane and then use the x value to be the top end of the domain.  This fix is much easier!

Comment: I have coloured in my triangle 'white' and am now trying to label the point where the parabola intersects the plane. I have named  the path of both the plane and the parabola and used intersection to find the point.  The trouble is I am getting the origin as the point - clearly the first one.  How can i get the second point?

Comment: I have resolved the previous question by drawing the parabola a second time but starting its domain away from the origin.  Not tidy but worked!